# angular ngrx data showing id in new component add screen

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I cloned: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data and added a new component named alerts.  However when I click "add" on the alerts:

1. **It's showing the "id" field while it's not showing in heroes.**
2. **Save
   button is disabled while in heroes it's enabled.**

Can anyone tell what was is the difference between alerts component and heroes component that causes these problems?

**[see my source code here: ngrx-data-alerts-component](https://github.com/avidanyum/ngrx-data-example/tree/master/src/client/app/alerts)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `alert-detail.component.html` you wrongly named your `formControlName` to `symbol` instead of `name` wich is a required field `name: ['', Validators.required]`.

Change line 15 to this :

```
<input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="name" #name
              (keyup.esc)="close()" (keyup.enter)="saveAlert()">
```

[Here is a running fix.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qgybb3)

Comment: thanks, this has sorted out (2), save button disabled, why does the "add alert" screen shows the "id" field while the "heroes" add screen does not show any id field? thanks!

Comment: The `#symbol` should also be changed to `#name`, the `this.setFocus();` fails because the there is no element with the `name` id.